# How to avoid view overlapping in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have the following layout structure:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ContentNo1"> <-- Align top
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ContentNo2"> <-- Align bottom
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button/> <-- Always bottom of the page
</RelativeLayout>
```

My button is Bottom-Aligned in the FIRST RelativeLayout, and my ScrollView Top-Aligned in it...

I want to Top-Align ContentNo1 inside the second RelativeLayout, and Bottom-Align ContentNo2 inside it...

I've done this, but when ContentNo1 gets too big, it overlaps ContentNo2, I want it just to push ContentNo2 down... How to do that?

I've tried (as detailed in some topics around here), to use layout_below / layout_above, but when I use it, the Bottom-Alignment of the ContentNo2 is dismissed...

**-- EDIT --**

As Wasi asked, here are the pictures: (I can't post more than 2 links, then I've made this page to explain it)

http://www.mydonorlife.hol.es/relativeissue/

**-- EDIT 2 -- SOLUTION --**

This worked for me: I've removed the second RelativeLayout and set some weight/height tricks on some views as following >>

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                                                   <!-- CONTENT NO 1 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
            </LinearLayout>
                                                   <!-- /CONTENT NO 1 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
                                                   <!-- CONTENT NO 2 -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0">
                </LinearLayout>
                                                   <!-- /CONTENT NO 2 -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps someone later...

Comment: You can use match parent to the outer LinearLayout to make it full screen and then use layout_below / layout_above. Then bottom-alignment will not disappear. Because, using layout_below / layout_above you can make sure there is no overlap between two relative layouts.

Comment: That outer LinearLayout is already set with match_parent height and the bottom-alignment keep disappearing when I use layout_below / above

Comment: bottom-alignment disappearing means content2 is not fitting to the rest of the screen? Can you share a picture? An image might give a better description of this problem!

Comment: I've added them in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed some of your code and try to make a layout as you want.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- CONTENT NO 1 -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linerlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Top aligned text1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Top aligned text2"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!-- /CONTENT NO 1 -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linerlayout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="bottom aligned text1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="bottom aligned text2"/>
                    <!-- CONTENT NO 2 -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0">
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- /CONTENT NO 2 -->
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Button
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/scrollview"
            android:text="bottom button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

you can also add your **CONTENT NO 1** and **CONTENT NO 2** UI as per your requirement